# Performance with MySql query to load recent chat messages

Tags: mysql

I'm having some issues with performance for a MySql query for a chat application I'm in the process of building.

I'm trying to grab the most recent messages from a conversation. I'm testing with a table with approx 3 million rows in it (an export from an older version of the application). When loading from some conversations, it's quick. When loading from others, the query takes significantly longer.

Here's details on the table setup, it's an InnoDB table:

```
Column      Type                    Comment
id          int(10) unsigned        Auto Increment   
from        int(10) unsigned NULL    
to          int(10) unsigned NULL    
date        int(10) unsigned NULL    
message     text NULL    
read        tinyint(1) NULL [0]
```

And here are the indexes I have:

```
PRIMARY id
INDEX   from
INDEX   to
INDEX   date
```

This is an example of the current query that I'm running:

```
SELECT *
FROM `chat`
WHERE 
(`from` =2 and `to` = 342)
OR
(`to` = 2 and `from` = 342)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Now, when I run this query with this user combination (which only has a total of 325 rows in the database), it takes 1.5+ seconds.

However, if I use a different user combination which has a total of 12,000 rows in the database, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `chat`
WHERE 
(`from` =2 and `to` = 10153)
OR
(`to` = 2 and `from` = 10153)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Then the query runs in approximately 35-40 ms. Quite a big difference, and the opposite of what I would expect.

I'm sure I'm missing something here and would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction for optimizing all of this.

Comment: Both queries will do a table-scan regardless of the values you use. So I suspect you have just benefited from filling the buffer pool with pages from the table, and your second query is faster because it's reading from RAM.

Answer (score 0):

it's not about how much records the user has. you have created one table for all chats which is an issue when you try to fetch first 10 records of a user have inserted entries recently will be served fatser.

Comment: So if it's not going to scale well with the current setup, that's a problem. How would you recommend using multiple tables then?

Comment: either maintain two tables for a single chat if you have provided delete function.

Comment: or you can use single table for both with combination of user name

Comment: create table user1_user2(int  uid(10),varchar msg)

Comment: Would there be performance issues with having a ton of tables though? I hadn't really thought about that route. I guess the data storage wouldn't be an issue so much, it would just be loading and unloading the various tables. Right now we have approx 32,000 members, and hoping to grow that by a lot with the upcoming release.

Comment: Number of tables will not create burden.. and if you are growing i would recommend nosql and cloud

Answer (score 0):

Well, Another thing you can try is rather than using OR, use UNION which will give a little advantage.

Try to use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `chat`
WHERE 
(`from` =2 and `to` = 342)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM `chat`
WHERE
(`to` = 2 and `from` = 342)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Time taken by query in your case will also depend on how long ago any user messaged.

For that you should change your model and not have all messages in a single table.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like ultimately this isn't going to scale well then... How would you setup things to use multiple tables then? Not sure I understand what that data structure would look like.

Comment: Well, when it comes to big data handling , its best to break data over intervals. Considering your case, lets assume each week you get around 500,000 messages so for every week you create a table (More like Log entries). (Over time you cant start querying a table with 10 or 20 million messages looking for just past 10 messages of a user.)
Now After doing this you have to keep track of each user's last message sent, so that you can directly go to that week's table and query that or older tables. If this idea is inefficient then bring distributed computing environment.(hadoop and stuff)